# Polymer data from router to dom-element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I started with polymer 1.0 and created a new route endpoint as mentioned below.

```
page('/users/:name', scrollToTop, function(data) {
      app.route = 'user-info';
      app.params = data.params;
    });
```

so if I go to users/bob it will go to route "user-info"

in my index.html the route is defined as below

```
<section data-route="user-info">
   <web-homepage></web-homepage>
</section>
```

where web-homepage is a custom element.

the custom element is as defined below

```
<dom-module id="web-homepage">
  <template>
    This is homepage
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'web-homepage',
        ready:function() {
           //want to get the route parameters (eg: bob) here 
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Is there a way to get the value route parameter ":name" i.e bob inside the ready function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready` function is executed when the element is imported and created. If you access route params there, it will most likely be null/empty/undefined.

However you can pass route params to the element as below.

The `params` in `app.params` is the property of app. You can simply pass it to its child elements.

index.html should look like this

```
<section data-route="user-info">
   <web-homepage route-params=[[params]]></web-homepage>
</section>
```

Define the route-params in web-homepage

```
<dom-module id="web-homepage">
  <template>
    This is homepage
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'web-homepage',
        properties: {
          routeParams: {
            type: Object,
            observer: '_routeParamsChanged'
          }
        },
        ready:function() {
           //ready function is run during element creation. route-params will most likely be empty/null/undefined
           //Just random
           //want to get the route parameters (eg: bob) here 
        },
        _routeParamsChanged: function(newValue) {
           console.log('route params: ', newValue);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: _routeParamsChanged is undefined. I get this error now.

Comment: ah. figured it out. you have to give "_routeParamsChanged".